# shell-escape and "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified"

Tags: errors, texstudio, shell-escape, environment-variables

I am using `TexStudio 2.12.6` on `TexLive 2015 (Debian)`.
If I add the option `--shell-escape` to my compile command

```
lualatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error %.tex,
```

I get the error `tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified`.
Without the `--shell-escape` option, everything works fine.
What´s the reason for that error, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `--shell-escape` you are running an external command via a terminal. Which one should be used is set with `$TERM`. For example in my Ubuntu I get:

```
voss@shania:~$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

However, I suppose that you'll get nothing. In that case define `$TERM` before running `lualatex`:

```
export TERM=unknown
lualatex --shell-escape ..
```

Comment: `export TERM=xterm && lualatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in the configuration fails here with `Error: Could not start the command: export TERM=xterm && lualatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex`

Comment: try it by running it in a shell and _not_ from the GUI and use `TERM=xterm-256color`

Comment: it works fine from a real bash, but I would love to start the compiler from the Texstudio GUI.

Comment: put `TERM=...`. into your local `bashrc` file

Comment: Added `export TERM=xterm` in `~/.bashrc` for a test, but it did not change anything. TERM should not be set static in bashrc. The error does not occur, if I start texstudio from a terminal in X11, but it occurs if I start it from the menu. I think it is a bug in TeXstudio.

Comment: `xterm-256color`  not only `xterm`

Comment: did you restarted TeXstudio?

Comment: I tried xterm-256color now too. But TeXStudio seems not to start a bash, or evaluate the .bashrc after a restart. But I do not expect that TeXstudio does this. How should it know that the user does not use `zsh` for example?